# Google API Response Data: Count most frequent dictionary values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a Python script (Python 3.7) that accesses a Google Sheet and gets all of the data from the sheet using the `get_all_records()` method from the `gspread` library.

The response data is a list of dictionaries, with each row from the google sheet represented as it's own dictionary, and the key/value pairs as the column header and row values respectively like so:

```
[{'Away Team': 'Gillingham',
  'Bet': 'Over 2.5 Goals',
  'Home Team': 'AFC Wimbledon',
  'Timestamp': '10/17/2019 10:36:01'},
 {'Away Team': 'Liverpool',
  'Bet': 'Home Win',
  'Home Team': 'Man United',
  'Timestamp': '10/18/2019 22:59:18'},
 {'Away Team': 'Newcastle',
  'Bet': 'BTTS',
  'Home Team': 'Arsenal',
  'Timestamp': '10/18/2019 22:59:31'},
 {'Away Team': 'Man City',
  'Bet': 'BTTS',
  'Home Team': 'Everton',
  'Timestamp': '10/20/2019 20:29:45'},
 {'Away Team': 'Man City',
  'Bet': 'BTTS',
  'Home Team': 'Everton',
  'Timestamp': '10/20/2019 20:29:52'},
 {'Away Team': 'Man City',
  'Bet': 'BTTS',
  'Home Team': 'Everton',
  'Timestamp': '10/20/2019 20:30:00'},
 {'Away Team': 'Man City',
  'Bet': 'BTTS',
  'Home Team': 'Everton',
  'Timestamp': '10/20/2019 20:30:02'},
 {'Away Team': 'Newcastle',
  'Bet': 'BTTS',
  'Home Team': 'Arsenal',
  'Timestamp': '10/18/2019 22:59:31'}]
```

The values of the `'Bet'` key can be 1 of 8 values. For each unique value, I want to count the frequency of the values in the `'Home Team'` key across all of the dictionaries.

In the example above, the most frequent `'Home Team'` value for key-value pair `'Bet': 'BTTS'` is Everton

I tried creating new dictionaries for each unique `'Bet'` key value using `default dictionary` from the `collections` module but I soon realized I could only create new dictionaries with either the `'Home Team'` values as keys with the `'Bet'` value as the value but I can't then capture frequency.

The data on the sheet is collected via a Google form so I can be assured of the integrity of the data captured as the form only allows values to be selected from predefined drop-downs or radio buttons.

Some advice or pointers in the right direction on modules/techniques to help me out here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the collections module, but it's really easy to achieve using old-school, plain Python.

Supposing we have your list of dictionaries stored in a variable called `raw_dicts`. Allow me to suggest parsing it into a more convenient data structure for our task:

```
parsed_dict = dict()
for dictionary in raw_dicts:
    bet = dictionary['Bet']
    if bet not in parsed_dict.keys():
        parsed_dict[bet] = dict()
    if dictionary['Home Team'] not in parsed_dict[bet].keys():
        parsed_dict[bet][dictionary['Home Team']] = 0
    parsed_dict[bet][dictionary['Home Team']] += 1
```

What I did here is creating a counter for each bet-team pair. We get this beautiful dictionary:

```
{
    "Over 2.5 Goals": {
        "AFC Wimbledon": 1
    }, 
    "Home Win": {
        "Man United": 1
    }, 
    "BTTS": {
        "Everton": 4, 
        "Arsenal": 2
    }
}
```

Now that we have such a nice dictionary, all we're left with is a simple maximization problem, whose solution is by the textbook:

```
most_frequent_bet = ""
most_frequent_team = ""
highest_frequency = 0
for bet in parsed_dict.keys():
    for team in parsed_dict[bet].keys():
        if parsed_dict[bet][team] > highest_frequency:
            most_frequent_bet = bet
            most_frequent_team = team
            highest_frequency = parsed_dict[bet][team]
```

This could have been achieved by any number of other methods, some a lot more elegant and short than mine. What I wanted to do here is an easy-to-read code that goes step-by-step.